# Does "npm install" look for packages in local cache first?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I was trying to figure out how local cache is fitted in `npm install` flow. I did the following:

1. `npm cache clear --force`
2. `npm cache rd`
3. `npm install react@16.10.1`
4. I disconnected from the internet
5. I removed the `node_modules` directory
6. `npm install react@16.10.1`

The package got installed and a `package-lock.json` was created successfully; however the following warning in the console made me confused:

```
Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because the host is inaccessible -- are you offline?
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
...
...
```

1. Why did `npm` try to connect to the registry at all while the package does exist in the local cache? and
2. What was `npm` trying to get from the registry? Did it try to download the whole package or it just wanted to check some metadata like hash or so?